# Branch and bound algorithm

Tags: operations-research

Can someone helps with the following question:

Modify the branch-and-bound algorithm to use Lagrangian bounds instead of linear programming bounds. Discuss the advantages and drawbacks of such an approach.

Comment: Hello and welcome to math.stackexchange. This is an exercise question to make you think about (a) branch and bound, (b) Lagrangian bounds, (c) LP bounds. As such, it is far too vague. To make progress, consider a simple problem where you understand how the usual branch-and-bound works, then try to do it the other way and see what happens.

Comment: Yes, it is an exercise question. But we do not know how to include the lambda..